# mysqldump not saving output file in different directory

Tags: php, mysql

mysqldump is running fine in our server; we are executing it through system command. 
e.g -

> exec('mysqldump -h hostname -u userName -ppassword database_name >
>   dump.sql');

but when I want to make the dump file save in a different directory, like –

> exec('mysqldump -h hostname -u userName -ppassword database_name >
>   /backup/dump.sql');

I also have tried with full path, but the command fails to execute.
How should I solve this?

Edited: it was a permission issue, I solved it using changing permission to 700. Thanks to @DBK.

Comment: what about folder permissions ?

Comment: Do you have any error messages?

Comment: DBK, its 644, I dont have any error message, can you please tell me sectus how to see error log.

Comment: are u sure you have /backup folder? I guess you know when you use /backup it looks for that folder in root, not in current directory.

Comment: Hey DBK, I tried in your line and change the permission to 777 and it works, but that is not proper as per security risks. What permission should I give?

Comment: Bojan, I think its permission problem

Comment: with this new information, i agree.

Comment: @DBK, thanks a lot. I think 700 is fine.

Answer (score 0):

try the manual path for creating the dump-
use the following command
go to `cd/var/lib/mysql`

search for the database whose dump you want.

`ls -l | grep database_name`

`mysqldump database_name > database.sql`

//if you want to restore the backup

`cd /var/lib/mysql`

check the database name where you want to restore the mysqldump
`ls -l | grep database_name`

`mysql database_name < database.sql`

Comment: Thanks @sudeep 93, but it was just a permission problem, just changed the folder permission to 700 (be in safe side), and it works

Comment: sudeep, always try to highlight any commands or sample code using back ticks or indentation. check out [Markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)